# Why when I clicked the update button, all data in database changes?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am making a Library System where the user can filter the data in database (using SQLite). As of now, I am having a problem updating my database. When I select one item in the database then update it, all the data changes. How can I change only the selected item?

Here is my code:

```
package librarySystemPackage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class LibrarySystem extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public LibrarySystem() {
        initComponents();
        conn = DbConnection.ConnecrDb();
        updateTable();
    }

    private void updateTable() {
        String sql = "select * from LibrarySystemDatabase";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        tblTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel (rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {   
        }
    }
} 

    private void clearFields() {
        txtNo.setText(null);
        txtTitle.setText(null);
        txtAuthor.setText(null);
        txtGenre.setText(null);
        txtLexile.setText(null);
        txtPoints.setText(null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtTitle = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtNo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtAuthor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtGenre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtLexile = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtPoints = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnInsert = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tblTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        btnDeselect = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnUpdate = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Title:");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Accession Number:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Author:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Lexile:");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Genre:");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Points:");

        btnInsert.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        btnInsert.setText("Insert");
        btnInsert.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnInsertActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tblTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        tblTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tblTableMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        tblTable.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                tblTableKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblTable);

        btnDeselect.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        btnDeselect.setText("Deselect");
        btnDeselect.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDeselectActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnUpdate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        btnUpdate.setText("Update");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnUpdateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtPoints, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtLexile, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtGenre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtAuthor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 175, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(txtNo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                                .addComponent(txtTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 548, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                        .addComponent(btnInsert, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnDeselect)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnUpdate)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(122, 122, 122)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtNo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtAuthor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtGenre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtLexile, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtPoints, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 259, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnDeselect)
                    .addComponent(btnInsert)
                    .addComponent(btnUpdate))
                .addContainerGap(224, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnInsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String sql = "INSERT INTO LibrarySystemDatabase(txtNo, txtTitle, txtAuthor, txtGenre, txtLexile, txtPoints) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
            pst.setString(1, txtNo.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtTitle.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txtAuthor.getText());
            pst.setString(4, txtGenre.getText());
            pst.setString(5, txtLexile.getText());
            pst.setString(6, txtPoints.getText());
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted Successfully");
            updateTable();
            clearFields();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }                                         

    private void tblTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
       int row = tblTable.getSelectedRow();
       String selection = tblTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
       String sql = "select * from LibrarySystemDatabase where txtNo = " + selection;
       try {
           pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
           rs = pst.executeQuery();
           if(rs.next()) {
               txtNo.setText(rs.getString("txtNo"));
               txtTitle.setText(rs.getString("txtTitle"));
               txtAuthor.setText(rs.getString("txtAuthor"));
               txtGenre.setText(rs.getString("txtGenre"));
               txtLexile.setText(rs.getString("txtLexile"));
               txtPoints.setText(rs.getString("txtPoints"));
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       } finally {
           try {
               rs.close();
               pst.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }
       }
    }                                     

    private void tblTableKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
         int row = tblTable.getSelectedRow();
       String selection = tblTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
       String sql = "select * from LibrarySystemDatabase where txtNo = " + selection;
       try {
           pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
           rs = pst.executeQuery();
           if(rs.next()) {
               txtNo.setText(rs.getString("txtNo"));
               txtTitle.setText(rs.getString("txtTitle"));
               txtAuthor.setText(rs.getString("txtAuthor"));
               txtGenre.setText(rs.getString("txtGenre"));
               txtLexile.setText(rs.getString("txtLexile"));
               txtPoints.setText(rs.getString("txtPoints"));
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       } finally {
           try {
               rs.close();
               pst.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }
       }
    }                                    

    private void btnDeselectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
       clearFields();
       updateTable();
    }
```

This is my code for the update button

```
    private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String sql = "update LibrarySystemDatabase set"
                + " txtNo = '"+txtNo.getText()+"',"
                + " txtTitle = '"+txtTitle.getText()+"',"
                + " txtAuthor = '"+txtAuthor.getText()+"',"
                + " txtGenre = '"+txtGenre.getText()+"',"
                + " txtLexile = '"+txtLexile.getText()+"',"
                + " txtPoints = '"+txtPoints.getText()+"'";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated");
            updateTable();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {



        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LibrarySystem().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDeselect;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnInsert;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnUpdate;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblTable;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtAuthor;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtGenre;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtLexile;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtNo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtPoints;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtTitle;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update LibrarySystemDatabase` SQL statement has no `WHERE` clause, so **every row is updated** to the same values.

Your code should be:

```
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String sql = "UPDATE LibrarySystemDatabase"
                 + " SET txtTitle = ?"
                    + ", txtAuthor = ?"
                    + ", txtGenre = ?"
                    + ", txtLexile = ?"
                    + ", txtPoints = ?"
               + " WHERE txtNo = ?";
    try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pst.setString(1, txtTitle.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtAuthor.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtGenre.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txtLexile.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txtPoints.getText());
        pst.setString(6, txtNo.getText());
        int count = pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count + " Records Updated");
        updateTable();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Changes made:

- Use `WHERE` clause on the `txtNo` column, since that seems to be the primary key, according to your `SELECT` statements.
- Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for simpler handling of `close()`.
- Call `executeUpdate()` to get update count, and show it.
- Use `?` parameter markers, to prevent SQL injection attacks and SQL syntax errors, just like you already did for the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the line you are using to update:

```
select * from LibrarySystemDatabase
```

This is calling everything from the library system database, maybe specify which columns you would like to update in this method. In every other one of your methods you seem to specify where you want the data to go